# Weird halo around partially transparent objects in Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, transparency

I'm working on some Y trees for a game, and I noticed that when I switch to rendered view in the main viewport (using Cycles), the trees have this weird glowing halo around them:
[image: Glowing trees]
Here's what they should look like, in Material Preview (Eevee):
[image: Regular trees]
I can't figure out why this is happening, or what to do to stop it (besides switch to Eevee). Here's a picture of my node setup for the tree material, just in case:
[image: Node setup]
Here's my paint.NET export settings: [image: export settings]

Comment: Eevee and Cycles definitely treat alpha differently, but anyway did you happen to resize the dds file?  Often re-sizing an image with alpha causes edge pixels to show up like that, because the anti-aliasing changes on resize, so the alpha doesn't quite match the image anymore.

Comment: you could try a color ramp to shift the alpha edge and reduce the halo

Comment: @DaleCieslak I updated the post with my Paint.NET export settings. I did not resize the image.

Comment: have you tried DXT3?  If your alpha is a black/white cutout and doesn't have any smooth shading it might work better.

Comment: Looks like it's just light bouncing off. This is actually the correct behavior, eevee cheats when calculating light and shadows.

You might get the results you're looking for by relaxing the BSDF shader with something simpler. But probably you want to change light and shadow behavior.

Comment: @DaleCieslak I have tried DXT1, 5, and 3, and all of them have the halo issue. **However**, I just now tried using the original .png, as well as a .tga, and the halo is not present when using those file types. Strange that .dds would do it but .png wouldn't.

Comment: it could be the mipmaps, possibly.  Or the compression - dds files compress like crazy.